# Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, angular, codeigniter, typescript

If I do postman I'm getting this response

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 5
            [sku_id] => XYZ3
            [name] => Kanchipuram Silk
            [price] => 3500
            [category_id] => 2
            [description] => Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
            [popular_status] => 0
            [active_status] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 4
            [sku_id] => XYZ1
            [name] => Kanchipuram Silk
            [price] => 999
            [category_id] => 2
            [description] => Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
            [popular_status] => 1
            [active_status] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 3
            [sku_id] => ABC3
            [name] => Kanchipuram Silk
            [price] => 2530
            [category_id] => 1
            [description] => Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
            [popular_status] => 0
            [active_status] => 1
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product_id] => 2
            [sku_id] => ABC2
            [name] => Kanchipuram Silk
            [price] => 1525
            [category_id] => 1
            [description] => Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes
            [popular_status] => 1
            [active_status] => 1
        )

)
{"0":{"product_id":"5","sku_id":"XYZ3","name":"Kanchipuram Silk","price":"3500","category_id":"2","description":"Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes","popular_status":"0","active_status":"1"},"1":{"product_id":"4","sku_id":"XYZ1","name":"Kanchipuram Silk","price":"999","category_id":"2","description":"Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes","popular_status":"1","active_status":"1"},"2":{"product_id":"3","sku_id":"ABC3","name":"Kanchipuram Silk","price":"2530","category_id":"1","description":"Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes","popular_status":"0","active_status":"1"},"3":{"product_id":"2","sku_id":"ABC2","name":"Kanchipuram Silk","price":"1525","category_id":"1","description":"Etiam faucibus viverra libero vel efficitur. Ut semper nisl ut laoreet ultrices. Maecenas dictum arcu purus, sit amet volutpat purus viverra sit amet. Quisque lacinia quam sed tortor interdum, malesuada congue nunc ornare. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes","popular_status":"1","active_status":"1"},"status":"200"}
```

I tried getting this using the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  productCount: number = 4;
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost/sp/api/unsold_products';
  products: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getProducts();
  }


  getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

  getProducts(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

But now I'm getting this error in the console. I think the error is may be due to some html content that I get from server. But everything works fine in postman but not in here.

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I'm coding by using angularjs 5 and for server side I'm using codeigniter framework. Here is my CI controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Api extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Api_model');
    }
    public function unsold_products(){
        $response = $this->Api_model->fetch_unsold_products();
        print_r($response);
        $response['status']='200';
        json_output($response['status'],$response);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The reponse you're getting is not a valid JSON ( the Array(...) part at least), the rest seems to be correct

Comment: That's a PHP array, not JSON. You have to print the data as JSON on the server.

Comment: Can you be specific, where I'm wrong in my controller?

Comment: @RaghuAcharya, try using json_encode to create json in PHP. Your front end has no problem, It's the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Only JSON must be returned from the server. You have printed your data on the server using print_r(). That will result in these type of outputs. Remove print_r($response) from your code and check the output.

Comment: I removed print_r() and now came up with this error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by myself.
I added

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

in the first line of the controller. Here is the complete controller:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
class Api extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Api_model');
        $this->load->model('Generic_model');
    }
}
```

Hope this may help some one..